# random velocities when using simulation shader

Tags: glsl, webgl, shader, simulation, physics

I'm trying to implement a Fruchterman Reingold simulation using shaders.  Before implementing the compute portion in a shader I wrote it in javascript.  It works exactly as I expect, as seen here:

http://jaredmcqueen.github.io/gpgpu-force-direction/canvas_app.html

When implementing the compute portion in a shader, I get a stable structure that randomly drifts around the screen.  I cannot figure out what repulsion / attraction forces are causing my graphs to float around so unpredictably:

http://jaredmcqueen.github.io/gpgpu-force-direction/gpgpu_app.html

the core of the physics are from the repulsion / attraction functions:

```
//fr(x) = (k*k)/x;
vec3 addRepulsion(vec3 self, vec3 neighbor){
    vec3 diff = self - neighbor;
    float x = length( diff );
    float f = ( k * k ) / x;
    return normalize(diff) * f;
}

//fa(x) = (x*x)/k;
vec3 addAttraction(vec3 self, vec3 neighbor){
    vec3 diff = self - neighbor;
    float x = length( diff );
    float f = ( x * x ) / k;
    return normalize(diff) * f;
}
```

Any insight as to why gpgpu, simulation based shaders would behave seemingly random would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was iterating through the edges incorrectly.  Here's my new edge iteration:

```
float idx = selfEdgeIndices.x;
float idy = selfEdgeIndices.y;
float idz = selfEdgeIndices.z;
float idw = selfEdgeIndices.w;

float start = idx * 4.0 + idy;
float end = idz * 4.0 + idw;


if(! ( idx == idz && idy == idw ) ){

    float edgeIndex = 0.0;

    for(float y = 0.0; y < edgesTexWidth; y++){
        for(float x = 0.0; x < edgesTexWidth; x++){


        vec2 ref = vec2( x + 0.5 , y + 0.5 ) / vec2(edgesTexWidth,edgesTexWidth);
        vec4 pixel = texture2D(edgeData,ref);

        if (edgeIndex >= start && edgeIndex < end){
            nodePosition = getNeighbor(pixel.x);
            nodeDiff.xyz -= addAttraction(currentNodePosition.xyz, nodePosition);
        }
        edgeIndex++;

        if (edgeIndex >= start && edgeIndex < end){
            nodePosition = getNeighbor(pixel.y);
            nodeDiff.xyz -= addAttraction(currentNodePosition.xyz, nodePosition);
        }
        edgeIndex++;

        if (edgeIndex >= start && edgeIndex < end){
            nodePosition = getNeighbor(pixel.z);
            nodeDiff.xyz -= addAttraction(currentNodePosition.xyz, nodePosition);
        }
        edgeIndex++;

        if (edgeIndex >= start && edgeIndex < end){
            nodePosition = getNeighbor(pixel.w);
            nodeDiff.xyz -= addAttraction(currentNodePosition.xyz, nodePosition);
        }
        edgeIndex++;


        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem random, construction stabilizes in seemingly right state and moves out in constant direction.

It looks like you apply force in shader and then update your model's position on CPU side and this global model position should stay constant either should have been updated by another value.

From what i've seen in code i recommend to eliminate floating point comprasions (**compareNodePosition.w == -1.0 || 0.0**) and **continue** operator. Please say if it helped. I haven't looked into algorithms logic yet.

Comment: https://github.com/jaredmcqueen/gpgpu-force-direction/blob/master/shaders/sim-velocity.glsl

I'll revisit my positioning code to see if I find any gotchyas

Comment: Ok, I'll look into eliminating floating point comparisons.  There's a lot of moving parts to my project and the .w values are set by me when I create the position textures.  They aren't overwritten in the shader - I only modify the xyz values.  w should always stay the same

Comment: I provide the texture print outs if you run the demos with your dev console open.  I console.log out the textures

Comment: one last thing -- I'm pretty sure the algorithms are just fine.  I feel that I may be iterating too much through the different nodes and edges, which accounts for the extra velocity I'm seeing